# Trying to use a class in a php page embedded with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

I'm trying to use a class that is already declared.

When the user types in something in the username text box I've used a javascript function to load a php file where it checks wether a username is available. this file is recalled for every keypress.

A connection to my database, which is a class, is already declared on the main page, however, the php file can't actually use the database classes. What can I do?

If I wrote a separate script to connect to the database it works, but I don't want to do that.

Contents of Php File:

```
        $query("SELECT username FROM client WHERE username = :username");
        $query_params = array(
            ':username' => $username
            );
        $db->DoQuery($query);
        $check_num_rows = $db->fetch();

        if ($username == NULL)
            echo 'Choose a Username';
        else if (strlen($username)<=3)
            echo 'too short.';
        else {
            if ($check_num_rows ==0)
                echo "Available!";
            else if ($check_num_rows >= 1)
                echo "Not Available.";
        }
        ?>
```

body.php

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#wowson').load('functions/check_username.php').show();
  $('#username_').keyup(function() {
    $.get('functions/check_username.php', { username: forms.username.value },
      function(result) {
        $('#wowson').html(result).show();
      });
  });    
  });
 </script>

<label>Username:</label><br>
<input id="username_" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
<div id="wowson">
       </div>
```

database class

```
 class database {
        public function initiate() {
          try
          {
            $this->database = new PDO("mysql:host='host';dbname='db", 'user, 'pass');
          }
          catch(PDOException $e)
          { 
            $error = "I'm unable to connect to the database server.";
            die("Failed to connect to database: " . $e->getMessage());
          }

        }

        public function DoQuery($query, $query_params) {
          try
          {
            $this->result = $this->database->prepare($query);
            if ($query_params != null)
            {
              $this->result->execute($query_params);
            }
            else
            {
              $this->result->execute();
            }
          }
          catch(PDOException $e)
          {
            die();
          }
        }
        public function fetch() {
          return $this->result->fetch();
        }
 }
```

Comment: Join the database connection in the index in one file, use `include` or `require` to include the code in your new pages.

Comment: your code has syntax errors. Next to that what has been commented already: use include / require or learn about autoloading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load your original page, you are creating your object from your database class, right?

Well, when you are using Ajax to query the server about the username, that is a totally new request, and it knows nothing about the previous requests.

As such, just add something like `require_once('my/path/database.php'); $db = new database();` to your PHP script which responds to the ajax request.